# British or american english?

Tags: discussion

I think I can probably work out the answer to this already, but just to confirm - is the convention for spelling, and especially tags to use American English rather than British?

[This](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/542/how-do-you-remove-mold-from-a-tent) question was what made me consider it - originally I wrote "mould" but it was edited to the american "mold".

If it is a case of American English then I'll try to adhere but I'm afraid some things might need to be edited by you guys across the pond!

Comment: Where I live in Wales [mold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mold,_Flintshire) has an entirely different meaning to mould.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For canonical issues (such as tags), we tend to standardize on the American English spellings. But when it comes to someone's writing, I would **leave it to the preference of the author.** If a 3rd party becomes too insistent on performing minor edits to change all occurrences of 'favourite' to 'favorite', I would consider that somewhat abusive.

Comment: +1, I agree, this makes sense and is standard policy.